# Browsing sessions in Opera are no longer saved on next Opera startup

Tags: browser, opera, browser-tabs

After a long time of using Opera web browser without any issues, a really annoying one appeared today. I had about 10-15 tabs open for my regular use when I am surfing internet. The setting that I used has always been :

```
On startup : Continue where I left off
```

But today when I started Opera, my last browsing session was not there, and only an empty "start page" appeared. History however is saved properly. I also reinstalled Opera but it didn't help. I actually don't know what version was previously ( if it auto updates then probably latest ). But current version is 23.0.1522.60 . I have Win 7 x64.

I thought it could be an exceptional occurrence, so I tried opening a few tabs, and restarting Opera. But same thing happened, and browsing sessions are no longer saved.

Has anyone experienced that before or knows how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Sorry, works fine for me on the same version... so I take it you aren't using the dev channel. Do you leave all settings as default after a new install? If you can reproduce this on a plain vanilla version, is there anything "unusual" about your system setup?

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter - Thank you for your comment. I don't know what's a dev channel or vanilla version, I hope that helps in someway as well =) I don't think there is anything unusual about my system setup. I haven't been changing anything lately, and really can't explain why this Opera behaviour all suddenly now. =/ Quite frustrating, because now it is 10 times less useful to me without reopening the tabs that I use.

Comment: I hear ya. :-) And yes, if you don't know what it is, you're most likely _not_ on the dev channel. Just wanted to rule out that case. Sorry, don't have any other ideas since it works for me on the same version. You could try it on another systems if you have any, or hope someone else has the same problem and can help.